# react redux e-commerce like filters

Tags: filter, redux, filtering

I want to implement e-commerce like filters in my project,  I am thinking of managing all the filters in the redux store since filters can be modified from multiple places and then synching the URL  from the filter obj  of the store.
Finally, the API  request will be based on the Url.

Is the approach correct? Any advice or any useful links regarding this.

Comment: Redux would be a good tool to use in this case. I would start at the [Redux webstie](http://redux.js.org/) and work through the tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. Redux fit nicely.

Check my demo: https://store.cezerin.com/footwear

My Redux state contains this

```
productFilter: {
    search: '',
    categoryId: null,
    priceFrom: null,
    priceTo: null,
    attributes: null,
    sort: null,
    fields: '',
    limit: 30
}
```

in reducer

```
case t.SET_PRODUCTS_FILTER:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        productFilter: Object.assign({}, state.productFilter, action.filter)
      })
```

in actions

```
const setProductsFilter = filter => ({type: t.SET_PRODUCTS_FILTER, filter: filter})
dispatch(setProductsFilter({categoryId: '13213213'}));
```

I work on https://github.com/cezerin/cezerin - e-commerce platform with React, Redux and Node.js. It's SPA and PWA.